# Should we nuke "learning resources recommendations" answers / questions

Tags: discussion

Questions such as this which was dug back up due to an edit to update a link:

[Good resources for learning about game architecture?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/455/good-resources-for-learning-about-game-architecture)

Now almost 8 years old.

The issues I see with keeping it visible and search-engine-discoverable:

- It's unfair to other (better or worse) books/resources/authors that didn't make it into the answers before closing.
- Those works/resources will likely become stale to varying degrees and maybe not something I'd recommend to beginners.

For example as an extreme example I wouldn't recommend K&R's original first edition "The C Programming Language" to a beginner.

Or a book teaching Glide wouldn't be a very good starting point today either, eventually any suggestions will also contain obsolete information that will confuse beginners and affect the signal-to-noise ratio of good, up-to-date resources.

Comment: It's already a community wiki, intended to be easily edited to correct out-of-date information.

Answer (score 5):

All of the answers should be merged into a single one, which would list all of the still relevant information (so: edit the first with the content of the others, then delete the others).

Then the warning suggested by [DMGregory](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2681/40264) should be added to that answer.

This way we keep the content focused in a single answer, and users will only need to edit that single answer when need be.

Comment: I think if anything should be done, this makes the most sense. It's a community wiki, so having a single answer with all the resources allows others to modify/update/add/remove from a single list.

Answer (score 3):

Answers should be edited to include a header:

> **Warning:** this list of resources is not maintained and may be incomplete or outdated. We recommend using a search engine to get the latest updates in this area, or asking on discussion forums like [GameDev.net](https://gamedev.net) or [Game Development Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development)

This preserves whatever value there may be in the existing Q&A, while informing users that that they should apply their own judgement & research.

Answer (score -4):

Answers should be deleted but the question kept, closed, to keep the "duplicate of" feature.

Comment: I think the point of duplicate questions is to help users find answers to questions that have already been asked. If we delete the answers, they will not find answer to their question.

Comment: I'd agree - if we delete all the answers, I'd as soon delete the whole question, otherwise it's just a dead end cluttering search results.

Comment: The point of leaving it is so when people search to ask the same question, they find it's been asked and closed as off topic. Not sure it's worth deleting the existing answers.